# Event handler does not work when clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the site im working on I want users to be scroll and click on icons to "open" them up.For example if a user clicks the about us icon it would have a paragraph of info in which they can scroll up and down the text along with a back button. Though when I click the back button i cant trigger a action. I had added a button with JQuery, and added a event handler, trigger an action for when the button is pressed, i added an id and a class (for CSS reasons) though nothing works.

**HTML**

```
<script     
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<head>
  <title>Underscores</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-    
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css">
  </style>
  <script     
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js">
  </script>
  <script     
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="left" class="left">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png"     
alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="middle" id="theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt=""     

class="icons" id="aboutID"></div>
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt="" 
class="icons" id="jobID"></div>
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" 
alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="right"><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" alt=""></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;

}

div.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 390px;
}

div.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}

div.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 870px;
}

#left,#right{
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#middle{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
#theMiddle{
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.backButton{
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 140px;
}
```

JS

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
//the key strokes for the up and down keys

// Set up our container
const el = document.querySelector("#theMiddle");
// Create new SlotMachine
const slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});


document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  //Secret Code: EADWEARD
  anime({
targets: "div.right",
translateX: {
  value: 200,
  duration: 500
    }
  });
  anime({
targets: "div.left",
translateX: {
  value: -200,
  duration: 500
    }
  });

  if (e.keyCode == "40") {
    //this is down
//this will open it up
slot.prev();

  } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
    slot.next();
  }
}

//Scroll detection occurs here, without the scrollbar
$("html").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
  anime({
    targets: "div.right",
translateX: {
  value: 200,
  duration: 500
    }
  });
  anime({
targets: "div.left",
translateX: {
  value: -200,
  duration: 500
    }
  });
  var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
  if (delta < 0) {
//This is for the scrolling down
// animation opens up the brakets

slot.prev();

  }
      if (delta > 0) {
    slot.next();
  }
});


//this is for detecting clicks  for the divs in the middle div
// 1 = the 2nd image , 2 = the  3rd image
$(".middle div").click(function(){
  if($(this).index() == '1'){
console.log("the fucks");

$('#aboutID').fadeOut("slow", function(){
var div = $("<p id='foo'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                                                                             </p> ").hide();
//var but = $("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");
$('#theMiddle').replaceWith(div);
$('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
//$('#theMiddle').append("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
btn.className = 'backButton';
btn.id ='backButtonID';
var text = document.createTextNode("Back");        // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(text);                             // Append the text to 
<button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);                    // Append <button> to             
<body>
});


  }if($(this).index() == '2'){
    console.log("jobs page");
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#backButtonID").click(function(){
    console.log("lol");
  });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and copy your code, then click the button that looks like `<>`. There will be places where you can paste your HTML, CSS, and JS code. There is also a Tidy button, which will make it a lot easier to read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your event handler for the backbutton before the back button actually exists on your webpage. Because you dynamically build your back button when the ".middle div" is clicked the definition for the event handler needs to happen after this for it to work. Try this code snippet

```js
$(".middle div").click(function(){
    if($(this).index() == '1'){
    console.log("the fucks");

    $('#aboutID').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        var div = $("<p id='foo'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                                                                             </p> ").hide();
        //var but = $("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");
        $('#theMiddle').replaceWith(div);
        $('#foo').fadeIn("slow");
        //$('#theMiddle').append("<button id='secondbutton'>Second button</button>");
        var btn = document.createElement("button");        // Create a <button> element
        btn.className = 'backButton';
        btn.id ='backButtonID';
        var text = document.createTextNode("Back");        // Create a text node
        btn.appendChild(text);                             // Append the text to 
        document.body.appendChild(btn);

        //Define the event handler here after the btn has been created
        $("#backButtonID").click(function(){
            console.log("lol");
        });
                              

    });


      }if($(this).index() == '2'){
        console.log("jobs page");
      }
});
```

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;

}

div.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 390px;
}

div.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}

div.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 870px;
}

#left,#right{
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#middle{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
#theMiddle{
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.backButton{
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script     
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<head>
  <title>Underscores</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-    
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css">

  <script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js">
  </script>
  <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="left" class="left">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png"     
alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="middle" id="theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt=""     

class="icons" id="aboutID"></div>
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt="" 
class="icons" id="jobID"></div>
<div><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" 
alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="right"><img 
src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" alt=""></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-
slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
```